# How to get the sum of filtered fields in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I filtered values in SQL?

When I execute this query, I'm getting the result below.

```
SELECT Stock_TBL.StockID, Stock_TBL.ItemCode, Stock_TBL.ItemDescription,
       InvoiceItems_TBL.StoreName, InvoiceItems_TBL.Quantity
FROM Stock_TBL
INNER JOIN InvoiceItems_TBL ON Stock_TBL.StockID = InvoiceItems_TBL.StockID
INNER JOIN Invoice_TBL ON InvoiceItems_TBL.InvoiceNo = Invoice_TBL.InvoiceNo
GROUP BY Stock_TBL.StockID, Stock_TBL.ItemCode, Stock_TBL.ItemDescription,
         InvoiceItems_TBL.StoreName, InvoiceItems_TBL.Quantity
```

[image]

I want that filtered like the below screen shot. How can i do it (for this three tables are involving and only 5 stores).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to PIVOT the StoreName.  Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    Stock_TBL.StockID,
    Stock_TBL.ItemCode,
    Stock_TBL.ItemDescription,
    InvoiceItems_TBL.StoreName,
    InvoiceItems_TBL.Quantity
  FROM Stock_TBL
  INNER JOIN InvoiceItems_TBL ON Stock_TBL.StockID = InvoiceItems_TBL.StockID
  INNER JOIN Invoice_TBL ON InvoiceItems_TBL.InvoiceNo = Invoice_TBL.InvoiceNo
  GROUP BY Stock_TBL.StockID, Stock_TBL.ItemCode, Stock_TBL.ItemDescription, InvoiceItems_TBL.StoreName, InvoiceItems_TBL.Quantity
) t
PIVOT ( SUM(Quantity)
  FOR StoreName IN (
    [E M B],
    [LB],
    [SHOP],
    [WAT],
    [NIH],
    [AJITH]
  )
) p
```

Note that you will have to specify the list of stores manually.  If you don't want to do this, then research dynamic pivot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer answer. i'm getting error "Incorrect syntax near 'E M B'." how to fix What is PIVOT i'm new to SQL..

Comment: try changing it to [E M B]

Comment: thanks again working fine.. small problem if i update the Store name error will occur so can i use sql query inside the [ ] such as  PIVOT ( SUM(Quantity)
  FOR StoreName IN (
    [SELECT StoreName FROM Store_TBL WHERE StoreID = 1],
  [SELECT StoreName FROM Store_TBL WHERE StoreID = 2],
  [SELECT StoreName FROM Store_TBL WHERE StoreID = 3],
  [SELECT StoreName FROM Store_TBL WHERE StoreID = 4],
  [SELECT StoreName FROM Store_TBL WHERE StoreID = 5],
  [SELECT StoreName FROM Store_TBL WHERE StoreID = 6]
  )
) p

Comment: if i add query inside the box bracket i'm getting error.. how to solve that please help me

Comment: Can i specify the list of stores using select query because of when i change the column name i will get problem.. please help me...

Comment: @user1663855 please search this site for the words dynamic pivot.  That will be the technique you want the store names to be gathered automatically.